# Can monsters get past doors in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I understand there are monsters quite far down if you keep digging. Can they get past doors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doors can stop regular invaders, when the doors have been set to "forbid passage". Those doors can still be opened by thieves, who can pick the locks. Be careful though, because there are some monsters designated as "building destroyers" who have the ability to destroy doors entirely.

The best way I've found to stop things from getting in is with constructed walls. As in, breach the fun areas, then very quickly wall off that area until you are ready to deal with whatever you've found. Be quick with the walling though.

For more about doors, look here: https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Door

For more about building destroyers: https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Building_destroyer

Comment: Cool, so walls are completely safe then...

Comment: Be prepared for your dwarves to wall themselves in, i.e. on the wrong side of the constructed wall. You can prevent/reduce this by using traffic designations to prevent them standing on the wrong side during construction.

Comment: I've found the best way to avoid them walling themselves in is to tell them to build a wall where you don't want them standing, then pause the construction of that wall. They don't like standing in construction spaces, so will work from the other side.